# VBA - Vlookup not fetching from text lookup value

Tags: excel, vba

```
        Dim sourcewb As Workbook
        Dim targetWorkbook As Workbook
        Dim filter As String
        Dim filter2 As String
        Dim rw As Long
        Dim lookup As String
        Dim X As Range
        Dim y As Range
        Dim a, b As Variant

       Set sourcewb = ActiveWorkbook
        Set X = sourcewb.Worksheets(1).Range("A:G")
        Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
        Set sourceSheet = sourcewb.Worksheets(1)
        MsgBox sourceSheet.Name
        X.Select

    MsgBox sourcewb.Name

    filter = "(*.xls),*.xls"
    Caption = "Please Select an input file "
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Filename = Application.GetOpenFilename(filter, , Caption)
    Set targetWorkbook = Application.Workbooks.Open(Filename)
    Set y = targetWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A:G")
    y.Select

    Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
    Set targetSheet = targetWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    MsgBox targetSheet.Name & " This is the country code sheet name "

    Set targetWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook
    MsgBox targetWorkbook.Name
    y.Select
                              sourcewb.Activate
                        MsgBox ActiveWorkbook.Name & " IS the active workbook"

                        MsgBox sourcewb.Name

                        MsgBox sourcewb.Name & " This is the source workbook "
                        MsgBox targetWorkbook.Name & " This is the target workbook "
                        MsgBox "Trying to map from target to source "



                        With sourcewb.Worksheets(1)
                        For rw= 2 To Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

                             Cells(rw, 4) = Application.VLookup(Cells(rw, 1).Value, y, 4, False)
                             'MsgBox Cells(a, 4).Value2
                              Next rw
                        End With


                        MsgBox "All required columns from source mapped to target file "
                        Set sourcewb = ActiveWorkbook
                        MsgBox ActiveWorkbook.Name
                        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

I have a workbook sourcewb. I open another workbook targetworkbook from the sourceworkbook. My Columns in **sourcewb** are Sl No, Country code,country names

```
slno           country code      country name                Region     
  1               AL               Algeria                    
  2               US               USA                        
  3               UK               United Kingdom
```

My targetwb is

```
         country code      country name                Region     
               AL               Algeria                   EMEA    
               US               USA                       Americas   
               UK               United Kingdom            Europe
```

I am trying to fetch **Region** column from country code in the sourcewb as there is no slno in the targetwb and the order of country codes are not the same as sourcewb.

I get an error 2042. I have tried storing the target value with string, int, long, variant, nothing has worked till now.

Any suggestions or help would be really helpful.

Comment: (1) May I ask why you don't use a formula instead of VBA? A simple `=VLOOKUP()` should work here. (2) You should read and follow [VBA Best Practices: Avoid using SELECT or ACTIVATE](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/1107/vba-best-practices/9292/avoid-using-select-or-activate) and [Avoid using ActiveCell or ActiveSheet in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/1107/vba-best-practices/7264/avoid-using-activecell-or-activesheet-in-excel) to avoid any issues.

Answer (score 1):

With some "clean-up" and organization to your original code, try the code below.

3 comments:

1. When you are using a `With` statement, don't forget to nest all objects inside with a `.`.
2. Stay away from using `Select` and `Activate`, not only it's not necessary, it also slows down your code's run-time.
3. You need to trap the scenario that `Application.VLookup` will not find a value, and then you will get a run-time error.

Explanations inside the code as comments.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub AutoVLookup()

Dim sourcewb As Workbook
Dim targetWorkbook As Workbook
Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
Dim X As Range
Dim y As Range

Dim filter As String
Dim filter2 As String
Dim rw As Long
Dim lookup As String
Dim a, b As Variant

Set sourcewb = ActiveWorkbook ' set Activeworkbook object
Set sourceSheet = sourcewb.Worksheets(1) ' set source sheet
Set X = sourceSheet.Range("A:G") ' set source range

filter = "(*.xls),*.xls"
Caption = "Please Select an input file "
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Filename = Application.GetOpenFilename(filter, , Caption)

Set targetWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(Filename) ' set target workbook object
Set targetSheet = targetWorkbook.Worksheets(1) ' set target sheet
Set y = targetSheet.Range("A:G") ' set target range

With sourceSheet
    For rw = 2 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row ' get last row in column A
        ' make sure VLoookup found a match, otherwise you will get a run-time error
        If Not IsError(Application.VLookup(.Cells(rw, 1).Value, y, 4, False)) Then
            .Cells(rw, 4) = Application.VLookup(.Cells(rw, 1).Value, y, 4, False) ' this will fetch column "E" values
            'MsgBox Cells(a, 4).Value2
        End If
    Next rw
End With

MsgBox "All required columns from source mapped to target file "

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi @Shai Rado, Thanks for your explanation. I have learnt about cleaning the program a bit . Unfortunately as this is of my own interest I have been writing macros referring to a lot of Internet stuff than books. I will try to improve.                                                                  Coming to the output, I did add .Cells, .Rows etc , unfortunately I am sad for the fact that it is returning blanks for the checking the country code and fetching the other columns if I refer the country code..